# Cannot find module './util' at Storybook@Next

Tags: github-actions, storybook, webpack-5

To reproduce

I'm using Node v18.16.0 and React v5 + CRA and [migrate the storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#builderoptions-renamed) to lates version by running `npx storybook@latest automigrate`.

I've noticed that [Storybook@Next drops the Webpack4 support](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#webpack4-support-discontinued).

I got this list of Devdependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-coverage": "0.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^7.0.23",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/jest": "0.1.0",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/react": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "7.0.23",
    "@storybook/test-runner": "^0.11.0",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "0.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "storybook": "7.0.22",
    "webpack": "^5.88.0"
  },
```

And the `main.js` looks like

```
const config = {
  stories: [
    "../src/components/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-coverage",
    "@storybook/addon-docs",
  ],
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  staticDirs: ["..\\public"],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {
      fastRefresh: true,
      builder: {
        lazyCompilation: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
export default config;
```

Everything works fine on my local dev setup. Now, I create a Github Action. I copied the [YML configuration from this example](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/ui-testing-handbook/react/en/automate/).
As a result, the `./util` is not found as module.

The Log prints out:

```
Run yarn build-storybook --quiet
yarn run v1.22.19
$ storybook build --quiet
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './util'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/common/index.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/FileSystemCache.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/index.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/index.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/telemetry/dist/index.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/cli/bin/index.js
- /home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/storybook/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/common/index.js:30:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/common/index.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/FileSystemCache.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/file-system-cache/lib/index.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/dist/index.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/telemetry/dist/index.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/@storybook/cli/bin/index.js',
    '/home/runner/work/website/website/node_modules/storybook/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.16.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I checked

```
$ npm ls util
the-project
├─┬ @storybook/addon-docs@7.0.23
│ └─┬ @storybook/csf-tools@7.0.23
│   └─┬ recast@0.23.2
│     └─┬ assert@2.0.0
│       └── util@0.12.5 deduped
├─┬ @storybook/react-webpack5@7.0.23
│ └─┬ @storybook/builder-webpack5@7.0.23
│   └── util@0.12.5
└─┬ storybook@7.0.22
  └─┬ @storybook/cli@7.0.22
    └─┬ @storybook/core-server@7.0.22
      └─┬ @storybook/builder-manager@7.0.22
        └── util@0.12.5 deduped
```

How can I solve the issue?

Context:
[[Bug]: Storybook build and dev server not working after updating to Node.js 18](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19692)